# What is the correct path for the '--with-mysql=DIR' option for configuring PHP

Tags: php, mysql, compilation

I am trying to compile PHP from source with the MySQL extension as a shared library. The instructions provided by `./configure --help` say:

```
--with-mysql=DIR      Include MySQL support.  DIR is the MySQL base directory.
```

However, I have no idea what they mean by MySQL base directory! Is this the directory where the mysql client executable is? (e.g. on my machine /usr/bin). Or do they mean where the shared libraries (i.e. libmysqlclient.so and libmysqlclient_r.so) are located (e.g. on my machine /usr/lib)? Or some other place? I have tried several locations, but still when I try to use the compiled version of php I get the errors like:

```
Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the ./configure --help says it is the "DIR is the MySQL **base** directory.

Which would be the directory where MySQL was installed, in my case: /usr/local/mysql

You can try:

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

And look for the "basedir" config value

Comment: Ok, thanks for that command. In my case, the basedir config value is set to /usr. So it wasn't clear to me before that /usr was the base dir of mysql, since there are no mysql files in the root of that directory.